# Is it easy to convert (about 15 lines of code) c# code to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint-2010, content-type, document-library

I found [this code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cliffgreen/archive/2008/06/23/creating-a-link-to-a-document-item-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically.aspx) online and wondering if it's easy to convert to Powershell. I am getting this error

```
Missing expression after ','.
At C:\AddaItem.ps1:60 char:73
+         $newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($newDestinationFolderPath, <<<<
UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), $true)
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

It appears to be complaining about this line:

```
$newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($newDestinationFolderPath,UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(build
er.ToString()), $true)
```

Here's the whole code:

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
$SiteUrl = "http://portal.memorial.hermann/patient"
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
$Library = "Unpaid Billing Records"
$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$Library]
$rootFolder = $docLibrary.RootFolder
$csvFile = "C:\\PowerShell\insurancefile.csv"
# $fileURL

foreach($i in Import-CSV $csvFile)
{
    $sourceFile = Get-ChildItem $i.DocLink
    $destinationFolderPath = $rootFolder.Url
    if($i.DestinationFolder -ne ""){
        $destinationFolderPath += "/" + $i.DestinationFolder.replace("\","/")

        $folders = $i.DestinationFolder.Split("\")

        $subFolder = $rootFolder
        foreach($f in $folders)
        {
            $testFolder = $subFolder.SubFolders[$f];
            if($testFolder -eq $null)
            {
                $subFolder = $subFolder.SubFolders.Add($f)
                "created new folder " + $f
            }
            else
            {
                $subFolder = $testFolder
            }
        }
    }
    $destinationFolderPath += "/" + $sourceFile.Name

    "copying " + $destinationFolderPath
    if($i.ContentType = "MasterDocument")
    {
        $itemType = $docLibrary.ContentTypes[$i.ContentType]
        $newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($destinationFolderPath,$sourceFile.OpenRead(), $true)
        $theItem = $newFile.Item
        $theItem["ContentTypeId"] = $itemType.Id
        # $fileURL = $theItem.Url
    }
    elseif($i.ContentType = "Link2Document")
    {
        $itemType = $docLibrary.ContentTypes[$i.ContentType]
        $newDestinationFolderPath = "/" + $i.fileNameASPX
        $newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($newDestinationFolderPath,UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), $true)    
        $theItem = $newFile.Item
        $theItem["ContentTypeId"] = $itemType.Id
        $itemUrl = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue      
        $itemUrl.Url = $i.fileLinkUrl
        $itemUrl.Descrition = $i.URLDESC
        $theItem["URL"] = $itemUrl      
    }

    # UPDATING METADATA 
    # $theItem["Name"] = $i.newfilename #Rename file name
    $theItem["Status"] = $i.Status
    $theItem["Title"] = $i.Title
    $theItem["Grantor"] = $i.Grantor

    $theItem.Update()
}

$web.Dispose()
```

For reference, here's the C# code I'm trying to convert:

```
using ( SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite( "http://moss.litwareinc.com" ) ) {
    using ( SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb( "docs" ) ) {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Sample"];

        //link to the file
        string fileLinkUrl = "http://moss.litwareinc.com/docs/Shared%20Documents/ConfigureIRMinWSS30.doc";

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        using ( TextReader reader = new StreamReader( @"C:\linktodocumenttemplate.txt" ) ) {
            builder.Append( reader.ReadToEnd() );
        }

        //replace string template with values
        builder.Replace( "{0}", fileLinkUrl );

        //should change the name of the .aspx file per item
        SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add( "link_title.aspx", UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()));

        //set list item properties
        SPListItem item = file.Item;
        item["Content Type"] = "Link to a Document";
        SPFieldUrlValue itemUrl = new SPFieldUrlValue();
        itemUrl.Description = "From sample code";
        itemUrl.Url = fileLinkUrl;
        item["URL"] = itemUrl;
        //persist changes
        item.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain what "isn't working" and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to add the error. I updated the post.

Comment: this is better, but please also include your *powershell* code.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yes sir. I have upload my powershell code here http://wikisend.com/download/429800/Add_Files_PS.txt

Comment: thanks, but in the future, please include the code inline as I've done for you.

Comment: Use the reflector add-on (if you have a licensed reflector) - http://blog.lekman.com/2011/10/converting-c-to-powershell.html

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal: I wish they would let me download reflector. I am still looking for some help. I am just stuck on few lines.

Comment: Have a look at this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpswk-4ykcc&t=105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the error you're getting:

```
$content = get-content "C:\linktodocumenttemplate.txt"
$utf = new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($newDestinationFolderPath, $utf.GetBytes($content.ToString()), $true)
```